# Issue deleting a single row from a table with multiple sections (Swift 4)

Tags: uitableview, swift4, delete-row, sections

I'm trying to delete a row from a section in my table with multiple sections using commit editingStyle.  However, it's deleting the proper indexPath.row from the section above.

How can I get it to delete from the proper section?

I followed a couple of examples on how to section a single array and index it for the tableView.  I am unable to properly delete from the initial Array of custom class objects.  I am also unable to find a way to transfer the IndexPath Section and Row to a second view controller to display the selected Code.  It just transfers the indexPath.row but I can't get it to send the entire indexPath including the section.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == firstTableView {
        if editingStyle == .delete { 
            if inSearchMode == false {
                codeArray.remove(at: [indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
                userDefaults.setValue(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: codeArray), forKey: "codeArrayKey")
                userDefaults.synchronize()
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let subArrayArray = codeArray.compactMap { $0.subArray as? String }
    var dic = [String:[Code]]()
    subArrayArray.forEach {
        let subArrayKey = $0
        let filterArray = codeArray.filter { $0.subArray as? String == subArrayKey }
        dic[$0] = filterArray
    }

    let sectionTitle = sectionTitles[section]
    let sectionCodes:[Code] = dic[sectionTitle]!

    if tableView == firstTableView {
        if inSearchMode == true {
            return filteredCodeArray.count
        } else {
            return sectionCodes.count
        }
    } else if tableView == autoTableview {
        return locationFilteredCodeArray.count
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if tableView == firstTableView {
        if inSearchMode == false {
            indexCodes(enterArray: codeArray)
            return sectionTitles.count
        } else if inSearchMode == true {
            return 1
        }
    }
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == firstTableView {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newCodesProtoCell") as? NewCodesViewCell {
            let code: Code!

            if inSearchMode == true {
                code = filteredCodeArray[indexPath.row]
                cell.configureCell(code: code)
            } else {

                let subArrayArray = codeArray.compactMap { $0.subArray }
                var dic = [String:[Code]]()
                subArrayArray.forEach {
                    let subArrayKey = $0
                    let filterArray = codeArray.filter { $0.subArray == subArrayKey }
                    dic[$0] = filterArray
                }

                let sectionTitle = sectionTitles[indexPath.section]
                let sectionCodes:[Code] = dic[sectionTitle]!
                code = sectionCodes[indexPath.row]
                cell.configureCell(code: code)
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondNewCodesProtoCell") as? SecondNewCodesProtoCell {
        let code: Code!
        if locationFilteredCodeArray.count != 0 {
            locationAuthStatus()
            code = locationFilteredCodeArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureSecondCell(code: code)
        }
        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

This is how I'm getting the array of index names (headers) as this may be causing some of the issues.
  This is written to index the [Code] by the second letter in the .location.

```
func indexCodes(enterArray: [Code]) {
    var codeValues = [String]()
    for code in enterArray {
        var initCodeKey = String(code.location.prefix(2))
        initCodeKey.remove(at: initCodeKey.startIndex)
        let codeKey = initCodeKey.capitalized
        codeValues.append(codeKey)
    }

    var encountered = Set<String>()
    var result: [String] = []
    for value in codeValues {
        if encountered.contains(value) {
        } else {
            encountered.insert(value)
            result.append(value)
        }
    }
    sectionTitles = result.sorted(by: <)
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell what is your codeArray, Is it array of dictionaries? And You should not reload the UITableView. You should reload a particular row in section. self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade). And you are not removing the object from your codeArray correctly.

Comment: codeArray is an array of a custom class.  I am looking for the proper way to remove one row from the indexed table.

Comment: I'm open to other ways to properly reload the data after removing the row.

Comment: You need to remove object of you custom class at particular index. Could you share the code for you UITableView Data source, numberOfRows and numberOfSections

Comment: Thank you Nancy.  I added the code blocks you asked for to the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 steps. 
1. From your codeArray, get the dictionary from indexPath.section and then your Code object from [Code] saved in that dictionary. Remove code at indexPath.row and then reserve it to dictionary and replace dictionary object in CodeArray
2. self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == firstTableView {
        if editingStyle == .delete { 
            if inSearchMode == false {
                codeArray.remove(at: [indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
var dict = codeArray[indexPath.section]
let key = dict.allKeys.first
var codes = dict[key]

//remove code from [Code]
codes.remove(at: indexPath.row)
dict[key] = codes
codeArray[indexPath.section] = dict
                userDefaults.setValue(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: codeArray), forKey: "codeArrayKey")
                userDefaults.synchronize()
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: indexPath.row,       section: indexPath.section)], with: .fade)
            }
        }
    }
```

let me know if you find any issue implementing it.

Comment: This gives me the error  --  Value of type 'Code' has no member 'allKeys'  .. When I print "dict" it returns a single instance of the class Code instead of an array of the section items.

Comment: I need to reverify your structure. Please send me the code where you are adding objects to your codeArray.